# Elasticsearch regexp query finds no results

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I've a problem to build the correct query. I have an index with a field "ids" with the following mapping:

```
"ids" : {
  "type" : "text",
  "fields" : {
    "keyword" : {
      "type" : "keyword",
      "ignore_above" : 256
    }
  }
}
```

A sample content could look like this:

```
10,20,30
```

It's a list of ids. Now I want to make a query with multiple possible ids and I want to make a disjunction (OR) so I decided to use a regexp:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "query_string" : {
                        "query" : "Test"
                    }
                },
                {
                   "regexp" : {
                       "ids" : {
                            "value" : "10031|20|10038",
                            "boost" : 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size" : 10,
    "from" : 0
}
```

The query is executed successfully but with no results. I expected to find 3 results.

Comment: The thing is that you need to match the whole string. If those comma separated values were a single string, you could use something like `(10031|20|10038)(,(10031|20|10038))*`, but it does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get 10031 or 20 or 10038, you need to add parenthesis.
Change "10031|20|10038" => "(10031|20|10038)"